# How to render an action from another action in Symfony 1

Tags: php, symfony1, class-visibility

I am stuck with a Symfony application using version 1.0.17 which can't be upgraded at the moment.

Right now there is a page that contains an iframe which loads a webpage of a different action from the same module.  The iframe is causing some design issues as well and some user-experience issues so I want to get rid of it and just render the HTML from the iframe directly in the page.

I just can't figure out how to execute another action and render the view template into a variable that I can assign to the calling action's view.

I've tried `getPresentationFor()` but that either results in a 404 on the calling page, an exception or fatal error depending on how I try it.

I think I need to put the code in the `execute` method of the action.  The controller is an `sfAction` object.  If I call `$this->getController()` I get an `sfWebController` object.

Calling:

```
$this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'ContactIframeAction');
```

Results in a blank page; any code after that call does not get executed but if I output something before it I can see it on the page.  No errors in the server error log.

Calling:

```
$this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'ContactIframe');
```

just causes our 404 page to show so I think the previous call is closer to what I want.

Is there a way to render the output of another action from another action's code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably

```
$this->theContent = $this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'contactIframe'); // minus 'c'
```

Use :

```
// modules/mymodule/actions/actions.class.php
class myPageActions extends sfActions {

    public function executeIndex() {
        // ...
        $this->theContent = $this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'contactIframe');                  
    }
}

// modules/mymodule/templates/indexSuccess.php
<?php echo $theContent ?>
```

Comment: I tried `echo 'hi';
  $this->theContent = $this->getController()->getPresentationFor('schools', 'contactIframe');
  echo 'bye';` and all I see on the page is `hi`.  Nothing shows up in the error log.  I put a die statement in the contactIframe action but it doesn't seem to get that far.  There are some warnings output after `hi` but none that seem like it should break this page.

Comment: I think you are correct.  It appears the 404 page I am seeing is generated by the iframe and at this point I'm going to guess its because it can't see a certain variable or parameter so it serves a 404 rather than showing the form.

Comment: I added info on my post. Tell me if you need more

Comment: Worked like a charm, I just had to make it `ContactIframe` not `contactIframe`.  The 404 was because the iframe page was looking for a request parameter and it wasn't set so it showed a 404.  I figured out how to use `$this->getRequest()->setParameter()` to inject the required parameters into the iframe request.  Thanks again!

Comment: OK. I've suggested camelCase since it's symfony1 best practice.

Comment: Makes sense :) its the most poorly written code I've ever seen so that's what you get. Good to know so I can do that for any future stuff.